# Why can't Rust access private fields when a struct is in a different module?

Tags: rust, constructor, private-members

```
constructors
    |---------src
    |          |----------lib.rs
    |          |----------constructor_file.rs    
    |
    |----------Cargo.toml
    |----------main.rs
```

**lib.rs**

```
pub mod constructor_file;
```

**constructor_file.rs**

```
pub struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new(name: String, age: u32) -> Person {
        Person { name, age }
    }
    pub fn show(self)
    {
        println!("Name: {}, Age: {}", self.name, self.age);
    }
}
```

**main.rs**

```
use constructor_lib::constructor_file::Person;

fn main() {
    let person = Person { name: "Alice".to_string(), age: 33 };
    person.show();
    let person2 = Person::new("Bob".to_string(), 99 );
    person2.show();
}
```

**cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "constructor_lib"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[[bin]]
name="constructor_exe"
path="main.rs"
```

The above project is giving me the following build error

```
C:\git\Rust examples\constructors>cargo build
   Compiling constructor_lib v0.1.0 (C:\git\Rust examples\constructors)
error[E0451]: field `name` of struct `Person` is private
 --> main.rs:4:27
  |
4 |     let person = Person { name: "Alice".to_string(), age: 33 };
  |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ private field

error[E0451]: field `age` of struct `Person` is private
 --> main.rs:4:54
  |
4 |     let person = Person { name: "Alice".to_string(), age: 33 };
  |                                                      ^^^^^^^ private field

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0451`.
error: could not compile `constructor_lib` due to 2 previous errors

C:\git\Rust examples\constructors>
```

Why doesn't this error show up when I keep `Person` in the same file as `main.rs`?

**main.rs**

```
//use constructor_lib::constructor_file::Person;
pub struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: u32,
}

impl Person {
    pub fn new(name: String, age: u32) -> Person {
        Person { name, age }
    }
    pub fn show(self)
    {
        println!("Name: {}, Age: {}", self.name, self.age);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let person = Person { name: "Alice".to_string(), age: 33 };
    person.show();
    let person2 = Person::new("Bob".to_string(), 99 );
    person2.show();
}
```

Comment: Visibility/privacy in Rust happens at the module level, not the type level. A private field is only visible within the module that declares it (including any sub-modules).

Comment: @JoeClay, `let person = Person { name: "Alice".to_string(), age: 33 };` How can I make this notation work then? Or, is it unusable?

Comment: You would need to declare the fields as `pub` or `pub(crate)` for them to be visible outside of the module. A struct can only be constructed if all of the fields are visible (which is why many structs have a constructor function in their `impl` block).

Comment: @JoeClay, so, the answer is NO.

Answer (score 3):

Because [that's how visibility works in Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html)?

> If an item is private, it may be accessed by the current module and its descendants.

If the structure is defined in `main.rs`, then `main.rs` is part of "the module or its descendant", thus private fields are accessible.

If the structure is defined in a sub-module, then `main.rs` is *not* part of "the module or its descendant", and private fields are not accessible.

As [also documented in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html#pubin-path-pubcrate-pubsuper-and-pubself), and unlike many other languages, because Rust's privacy baseline is so restrictive you have a lot more flexibility in defining visibility than just "public".

Notably, you can define a symbol as `pub(super)` to make it accessible from the parent module, and `pub(crate)` to be accessible from the entire crate.

In many languages (e.g. java) the default is something like `pub(crate)`, and "private" has to be opted in. In Rust, it's the other way around, "private" is the default (although it's a bit more relaxed than Java's own `private`, I think).

Comment: `let person = Person { name: "Alice".to_string(), age: 33 };` How can I make this notation work then? Or, is it unusable?